# Ring functions which 'respects' homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $R$ be a ring, and $\varphi \in End(R) $ an homomorphism. We define
$$ S_{\varphi} = \{f:R\ \rightarrow\ R \ | \varphi(a) = \varphi(b) \ \Rightarrow \ \varphi(f(a))=\varphi(f(b))\ \} $$
In a certain sense, this is the set of functions 'respecting' $\varphi$. Consider
$$ \mathcal{H}_R= \bigcap_{\varphi \in End(R)} S_{\varphi} $$

(i) Show that $\mathcal{H}_R$ is a ring with the operations on functions induced by operations of $R$. 
(ii) Show that $R[x] \subseteq \mathcal{H}_R$.

Motivated by (i), (ii), the real question I would like to ask you is: 
(iii) Does it hold $\mathcal{H}_R \subseteq R[x] $ for every ring $R$? If not, can you find a counterexample?

Comment: $R[x]$ is not contained in $\mathcal{H}_R$. What you intended is probably not $R[x]$, the ring of polynomials but the ring of polynomial *functions* with coefficients in $R$. This is a certain quotient of $R[x]$ and may or may not be the quotient by the zero ideal depending on $R$. For example it is equal to $\mathbb{R}[x]$ if $R=\mathbb{R}$, but equal to $\mathbb{F}_q[x] / (x^q-x)$ if $R=\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: This reads like a homework problem.  Is it?  Mathoverflow is not an appropriate place for homework problems.  I recommend asking this question instead at our "sister site" math.stackexchange, which encourages a wider range of questions, from undergraduate homework to advanced research level.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to field the first two questions, go right ahead. They just involve chasing the definitions. (I agree with comments that this reads like a homework problem).

For question (iii), I encourage you to think of a ring whose only endomorphism is the identity. For example, if $R$ is any ring where a homomorphism $f: R \to S$ is uniquely determined by what it does to $1 \in R$ (which implies there is at most one such ring homomorphism $f$ for any ring $S$, since $1 \in R$ must be taken to $1 \in S$), then $R$ has that unique endomorphism property. Based on this, you should be able to come up with examples right away. Now, what would this imply for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for my superficial exposition. Points 1,2 are quite straightforward, and I wrote them just to motivate point 3. Next time I will avoid redondant questions. I formulated it long time ago and I misread my notes. I thought a bit to the problem, and I also changed the final question.

Let $R$ be a ring such that $|R| = |\mathbb{N}|$. Let $I_R$ be the set of ideals in $R$. We define
$$ S_J = \{f:R\ \rightarrow \ R\ | \ \forall a,b \in R: \ a + J = b+ J \ \Rightarrow \ f(a) + J = f(b) + J \} $$
and then $ \displaystyle \mathcal{H}_R = \bigcap_{J \in I_R} S_J$. Show that $\mathcal{H}_R$ contains a non-countable number of non-polynomial functions.

However, this was not a homework problem. The original problem was if $\mathcal{H}_{\mathbb{Z}} $ contains non-polynomial functions; i.e. if does exist a non polynomial function $f$ such that $a \equiv b \pmod{n} \ \Rightarrow \  f(a) \equiv f(b) \pmod{n} $ 
and this does not seem a trivial question to me.

Comment: Okay, I see; thanks for your explanation. As a moderator on another site, let me encourage you simply to post a new question rather than ask what you meant to ask in an answer box (usually this is frowned upon in StackExchange sites). I agree that the modified question is much less trivial than the question asked above, although I still believe that it is appropriate for this site (as opposed to MathOverflow).

Comment: Thank you for the availability! I will post a new question. Should I remove this wrong post?

Comment: Yes, I think it's appropriate practice to delete this answer once you post the new question. You should also feel free to link to this thread in the new question, explaining that the new question is what you really meant to ask. (By the way, I tune in to M.SE somewhat irregularly; hopefully though someone knowledgeable will respond to your new question, which is a good one in my opinion.)

Comment: Ok, thanks. My english is quite rusty: what do you mean by 'I tune in to MSE somewhat irregularly'?

Comment: It means that I don't visit this site regularly (and so might not notice your post when it appears). "Tune in" is mainly a radio or TV reference, as when you go to a specific channel at a specific time to "tune into" a show. "M.SE" is short for Mathematics StackExchange.